# How to make my SQL query search several words in the sentence even if they do not follow each other

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a SQL query for my search form.

```
$term = $request->get('term');

$queries = Article::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')->published()->get();
```

My research is working. If I have an article called "my great article is awesome" and that I write in my search form "greate article" it works.

But if I write "article awesome", the words do not follow each other, and it does not work.

How do I get my query to work just with keywords?

Thank you

Comment: Explode the string on spaces so you get an array with the words. Loop through the list and add a `where('title', 'like' ....)` for each word.

Comment: I guess you could technically split your search term into separate words, then rearrange them in all possible permutations and use LIKE permutation 1 OR LIKE permutation 2 etc. But that would be very inefficient... There should be a simpler way. Let me do some more research...

Comment: This isn't what MySQL's good at. This kind of problem crops up fairly often - especially amongst geneticists. After messing around with some sql functions for a bit, invariably people seem to wind up handling the logic in application code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like follows:

```
$term = $request->get('term');
$keywords = explode(" ", $term);

$article = Article::query();
foreach($keywords as $word){
    $article->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$word.'%');
}

$articles = $article->published()->get();
```

If you want only results that contain all the words in the query just replace the `orWhere` with `where`.

If you want to filter out certain words you could add something like:

```
$filtered = ["a", "an", "the"];
$filteredKeywords = array_diff($keywords, $filtered);
```

Alternatively you can pass a closure if you want to be more dynamic:

```
$filteredKeywords = array_filter($keywords, function($word) {
    return strlen($word) > 2;
});
```

Comment: Great answer. Was actually writing the same thing when I saw this answer. +1

Comment: @chasenyc With this method, how do I filter words? For example, I do not want to "a" "the" "an" and so on… Thank you !

Comment: @Jeremy I've added some options for filtering out certain words.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try something like that

```
$search = "article awesome";
$search = preg_replace("#\s+#", '%', $search);
```

replacing spaces with '%' will resolve the case you mentioned

Comment: But if the search term contains the words in reverse order, `awesome article`, then it can't find the article

Comment: i added another answer for you, i hope it's what's your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make the search ignoring the words order this should work

```
$search = trim(" article awesome great ");
$search = preg_split("#\s+#", $search);
$where =  "WHERE column like '%" .  implode( "%' AND column like '%", $search ) . "%'";
```

however it will take more execution time and resources on the server,

also think to add some injection escaping to avoid sql syntax errors